# Best way to test if method inside object was executed

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I created this little piece of code

```
function myFunction() {
  var myObject = {
    objProperty: "string",
    objMethod: function() {
      return myObject.objProperty;
    }
  };

  return myObject.objMethod();
};
```

Now I am trying to make unit tests which will check if the code works as it's supposed to:

```
describe("checking syntax and function integrity", function(){

    // called before each spec is ran
    before(function(){

    });

    it ("should return 'string' when myFunction is called", function(){
        Test.assertEquals(myFunction(), 'string', 'myFunction did not return "string"');
    });

    it ("should check if myObject.objMethod was called", function(){

    });
});
```

My question: is it possible to check if myObject.objMethod was called? I am using the test framework as supplied by [CodeWars](http://www.codewars.com/r/hFSZoA).

[Here is a link to their test framework](https://www.codewars.com/docs/js-slash-coffeescript-test-reference).

Comment: `Test.callCount(methodName) → Integer`
Returns the number of times a Test method has been called. Useful when creating kata that need to test the usage of Test methods. Also useful when using Test helper methods are disallowed within the kata solution. You can simply test if any disallowed calls have been made.

Comment: Could you please provide an answer as to how you think the test should be written?

Comment: hmm actualy it seems it's related only to the test methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this testing framework does not support such a thing. But you can do something like this:

```
it ("should check if myObject.objMethod was called", function(){
  let oldMethod=myObject.myMethod;
  let callCount=0;
  myObject.myMethod=function(){
    callCount++;
    oldMethod.apply(this,arguments);
  }
  //do stuff that should trigger the method
  //and then... check!!! :
  Test.assertEquals(callCount,1); 
});
```

**edit** : I didn't see that myObject was internal to `myFunction()`, sorry. So the answer is :

**you can't !** As myObject is not accessible from your test context. It does not even make sense to test it here as it is internal to your function. The only thing you can (and should) test is that the `MyFunction()`call returns a string, maybe a string that match some random criterias.

If at least it was not an object literal but an Object instanciated from a constructor function, it would deserve its own tests, but that's not the case here.

If you want to test the behavior of myObject, make it reusable: Create a `MyObject()` constructor, or pass the object via parameter to your `myFunction(myObject)` call.

Comment: let oldMethod = myObject.myMethod; //Returns ReferenceError: myObject is not defined

Comment: the fact is you can't test that if myObject is not instanciated in the test. Your test does not make any sense as you cannot test something that is not accessible.